# Loading Variable from a file

Tags: c++, file, file-handling, filehandle

AT

4 
5 
6 
7

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int data[4], a, b, c, d, e, f;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("tera.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        myfile >> data[i];
    }
    myfile.close();
    a = data[0];
    b = data[1];
    c = data[2];
    d = data[3];
    cout << a << "\t" << b << "\t" << c << "\t" << d << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

it takes AT also and give garbage value. how and where should i use ignore function  to ignore AT Value.
And there is one thing more if there is another array given BT containing some value like this:
AT     BT
how to store BT's all values under it in an array?

Comment: "I have tried my best"  Please [edit] your question to show your best.

Comment: @DrewDormann 
 Done!

Comment: Please research first.  There are too many questions already answered about reading from files: ["StackOverflow c++ read from file"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+from+file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).  You may want to narrow the search by appending "into struct" or "columns".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews an u just tell me how to ignore AT for above code?

Comment: @Shani _You_ must learn to do the work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit bro m learning i have done many searches but nothing is working. :(

Answer (score 0):

You just have to skip the first line. You can also add optional error handling, otherwise read may fail for all line.

```
if (!myfile)
{
    cout << "can't open\n";
    return 0;
}

string temp;
myfile >> temp;
cout << "first line: " << temp << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    myfile >> data[i];
    if (myfile.fail())
    {
        cout << "error\n";
        myfile.clear();
        myfile.ignore(1000000, '\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Shani, you should be able to comment here because this is your own topic.

Comment: @Barmark bro i cant tag u in comment i tried may b u have some privacy

Comment: I made some edit, see if that works. You can't comment in other topics until you have more points. Clearly you can comment in this topic because it is yours.